# Is there a way to launch the personal browser from an Android For Work app by intent?

Tags: java, android, android-for-work

I have an Android for Work app installed and I would like to open the browser. The way with the classic intents work, but opens the browser in the work space.

Due to some network stuff, I need the personal browser to be used. Is there a way to tell the intent to start the personal browser instead of the work space browser?

Comment: What do you mean by personal browser?

Comment: Use webview inside your app

Comment: @scienticious When you have Android for Work, you have two personas on your smartphone. And you have also two instances of the chrome-browser. (One classic and one with the litte AndroidForWork-Symbol). The network connection for the Android For Work is usually configured in a different way, i.e. use a VPN to access the corporate network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView instead of other web browsers.

**xml code**

```
   <WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    />
```

**java code**

```
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
       // progress is the percentage of website loaded

        }
    });


    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in"); //url you want to open

    webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

**MyBrowser.java**

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

by using above code you can open brower in you app and it will not need intent.
for any query comment below.